# Why is it true that every set in $\mathbb R^n$ can be covered by a countable union of open balls?

Tags: measure-theory

Why is it true that every set in $\mathbb R^n(n\geq 2$ can be covered by a countable union of open balls?

This is the fact we are using in the definition of measure theory where outer measure of a set is defined to be the infimum of all countable open coverings of open balls covering that given set

How to be sure that one such covering exists?

Comment: Consider the collection $\{B(0, r) \mid r \in \mathbb{N}\}$.

Comment: why downvotes to start with?

Answer (score 3):

The restriction $n\ge 2$ is not needed, the same holds true for $n\ge 0$. The reason is simple, $\mathbb R^n$ itself is a countable union of open balls, in many many different ways. Try to find some of these ways, and figure out then why that (trivially) implies that every subset of $\mathbb R^n$ can be covered by countably many open balls.

Answer (score 3):

Let $A \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$ and consider the set of open balls $\mathcal{B} = \{B_r(q)\; | \; q \in \mathbb{R}^n$ has rational coordinates and $r \in \mathbb{Q}\}$.  Clearly $\mathcal{B}$ is countable and it forms a basis for $\mathbb{R}^n$.  Now consider the collection $\mathcal{B}' = \{B_r(q) \in \mathcal{B} | \; B_r(q)\cap A \neq \emptyset\}$.  Since the union over all $B \in \mathcal{B}$ cover $\mathbb{R}^n$, then certainly the union of all $B \in \mathcal{B}'$ will cover $A$.

Comment: Remind me — Does $B_r(q)$ mean a ball centered on a point $q\in\mathbb R^n$ with radius $r\in\mathbb R^+$?

Comment: Also, can we also define $\mathcal B=\{B_r((0,0,\dots,0))\ |\ r\in\mathbb N\}$ for your argument? Seems like a simpler set.

Comment: @columbus8myhw That is the intended definition of the balls in that set (coordinate $q$ and radius $r$).  It seems like picking balls centered at the origin with integer radii can work too.  I picked the collection I did because it's the standard basis for the Euclidean topology.